# extjs: Changing the value of a node

Tags: tree, extjs

I'm sure this is really simple, but i can't seem to find it anywhere!

All I am trying to do is change the displayed value of a tree node.  I thought that tree.getNodeById(myNode).text='HHHHH'; or tree.getNodeById(myNode).value='HHHHH'; would do the trick, but i get nothing.  What am i missing?

Thanks

Craig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's:

```
tree.getNodeById(myNode).setText('HHHHH');
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was pulling my hair out trying to find it!

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, in Extjs 4.0.7, this is the only thing that worked for me:

```
var node = selected_node.appendChild({
    leaf: true,
    text: "My Text" //doesn't work
});
node.set( "text", "My Text" ); //works
```

Comment: And in extjs 4.2.6 too.